# How to get an image uploaded and store it in the firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I have the following upload button.

```html
<input type="file" id="logo-image-upload" onChange="imageValidation()">
```

The following function gets called whenever an image is uploaded.

```js
    function imageValidation(){
        let storageRef = firebase.storage.ref('user-logos')
        let imageInput = document.getElementById('logo-image-upload')
        if(imageInput.files && imageInput.files[0]){
            let reader;
            reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (e) => {
                    storageRef.put(//Blob).then(function(snapshot) {
                        console.log("Image Uploaded")
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

What can I pass as the value of the Image so I can upload it to the firebase storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add your html code as well for better understanding.
But if your input is of type **File** you can directly upload it to the firebase.
There is no need to convert it in **Blob**.

You can refer the below code for achieving your goal.

```
    let uploadTask: firebase.storage.UploadTask = storageRef.put(imageInput.files[0]);
    uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
      (snapshot: any) => {
        let x: number = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        return subject.next({ status: x, fileUploadSuccess: false, fileUploading: true, fileUploadFailed: false, progress: true });
      })
```

I think you can resolve your issue by using this approach.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but can you explain what should I put in `${fileName}` and `file` variables specifically? Thank you.

Comment: if there are any folders under user-logos  then there is the use of child, otherwise omit that part. You can just write storageRef.put(). The variable file is your actual file to be uploaded.

Comment: In your case you can use storageRef.put(imageInput.files[0])